# Bluetooth wireless headphones are not showing up in the bluetooth devices list

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth, headphones, wireless-headset

Yesterday I have purchased the Sennheiser Momentum 4 headphones (Wireless), it works fine with my mobile phone and with my desktop PC as well. However, it is not showing up in the list of availble devices on my laptop. I can't make it work with the laptop. However the Bluetooth module of the laptop is working fine, I can connect other devices - all is good. The version of the Bluetooth is MLP 12.13. Please help. OS - Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

the problem was solved by updating drivers on my laptop and restarting both: the laptop and the headphones several times.

Comment: You can set this answer as solution, so it will be shown as solved.
Thumbs u for updating the question here.